# Continuity of a function not defined at a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

It was my understanding that in order for a function to be continuous at a point it has to be defined at the point. I am teaching myself analysis from the book

http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf.

I was working exercises on continuity and ran into a problem as given below:
[image]

1. Let $f,g$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Suppose $g$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $0$. Prove that $fg$ is continuous at $x=0$. Apply this to the function $f(x)= x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ $(f(0)=0)$ at $x=0$.

a. Clearly $f(x)= x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not defined at $0$. There is no point of talking about its continuity there. However, it does have a limit point there.

b. The main problem itself does not guarantee that $g$ is defined at $0$. Without such a specification/restriction on $g$ there is no question of talking about its continuity at $0$. I do not quite understand the problem really. If it is indeed defined, then we can show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} fg = f(0) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) = 0$ by using the fact that $g$ is bounded around $0$.

Please any answers are appreciated. Either I am confused about something or the Problem is plain wrong.

Comment: The task clearly states that $f$ is defined at $x=0$ as $f(x)=0$, so it is indeed defined there. Just not by the same formula as everywhere else.

Comment: $g$ is also defined at $0$ because the problem says at the beginning that $f,g$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand that $f(x) = x sin(\frac{1}{x})$ us defined at $0$. However, I guess I missed the fact the $f,g$ is defined on $R$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But your function $f$ *is* defined at $0$. Didn't you read that $f(0)=0$?

Besides, the problem states that $g$  is bounded in some neighborhood of $0$. Therefore, it is *defined*  in some neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Carlos: For $fg$ to be continuous does if not have to be defined at $0$ as well? Or is it the point that $g$ does not have to be defined at $0$? All you need is that it be bounded in some neighborhood of the point?

Comment: @RameshKadambi $g$ **IS** defined at $0$! the problem clearly states that $g$ is defined on **ALL** of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @RameshKadambi *Of course* that for $fg$ to be continuous it has to be defined at 0 as well. Did I say otherwise? What I wrote was that *both* $f$ *and* $g$ *are* defined at $0$.

Comment: @Carlos I got it. Thanks.